# MOPED: Could not resolve IP for: localhost:27017 (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, mongodb, localhost

I am trying to learn Ruby and how to connect it to MongoDB.

I have followed everything from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0KH5jbSneo) and when I'm trying to connect to localhost:3000 I get the following error

```
MOPED: Could not resolve IP for: localhost:27017, delta is 30.624691, error class is #<Resolv::ResolvError: Resolv::ResolvError>, retries is 0. Node is <Moped::Node resolved_address=nil> runtime: n/a
```

What baffles me is that it's struggling to connect to the localhost and it's driving me insane!

Can you please guide me as to how I can fix this?

Thanks!

PS: I'm running Rails on a Windows Machine

Comment: what does `ps aux | grep mongo` says?

Comment: I'm running on a Windows machine, sorry for not specifying

Comment: @JulioGarcia I wouldn't recommend to run ruby on windows... try linux.
Windows might be generating this error

Comment: Try `C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe` from command prompt

Comment: @imechemi the last line I get is 
    2016-05-26T10:07:06.996-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017

Comment: now open another command prompt and run `C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe` again

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6
connecting to: test

Comment: how is your rails app responding now?

Comment: Now it works, I didn't realize I needed to start both mongod and mongo to get it to work. I thought you only needed to run mongo >.>;; Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113089/discussion-between-julio-garcia-and-imechemi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open command prompt and run `C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe`and then open another command prompt and run `C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe`

Comment: I did that for the first time and it worked. However when I tried to do it again the same error happened again :(